# How to access fax on Windows?

Tags: windows, fax, tapi

I need to write a **Windows** utility which accesses the fax in my Brother printer and can perform the following tasks:

1. Send PDF files.
2. Save incoming faxes as files.
3. Access incoming caller ID (for caller blacklisting) and be able to answer only after specified number of rings.

I am not sure which API/library I should use for the task.

Most of my programming experience comes from Linux and because fax is becoming more and more obsolete tech I'm not sure about the results I got by googling.

Anything that can be interfaced with Python, Java, C++ would be fine.

Edit: I've just read [North Korea uses a fax machine to send threats to South Korea](http://blogs.wsj.com/korearealtime/2013/12/20/north-koreas-weapon-of-choice-the-fax-machine/). Maybe, I exaggerated about this obsolescence thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best would be TAPI, here's a link to the [QuickStart guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms734257(v=vs.85).aspx).
Free source and code for TAPI from [JulMar](http://julmar.com/tapi/)

That should get you started on the right path